# Why are commands inside of generator functions not executed?

Tags: python, generator

When you create a generator object in python like this:

```
def gen():
    print("Hello")
    yield 1

x=gen()

print(x)
```

the only console output will be: < generator object gen at xxx>. Why does it not print "Hello" as well? If you change the gen function to just return a value instead of a generator (so change out "yield" with "return"), the print command is executed so that the console output is:

Hello
< generator object gen at xxx>

Why does that happen? How can I execute commands inside of generator functions?

Comment: try running `next(x)`. Nothing is happening because you are not iterating over the generator.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So the code inside of the function creating a generator is only called as soon as you iterate, not as soon as the generator itself is created. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)

Comment: This https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/ should help you better understand generator functions are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a famous statement: everything in Python is an object. So when do this, you just assign generator to variable, that's it. You can do the similar with functions:

```
>>> def func():
...     pass
... 
>>> x = func
>>> x
<function func at 0x7f78f03662d0>
```

If you want to use the generating values, you should iterate through it, so for example:

```
>>> def gen():
>>>     yield 1
>>>     yield 2
>>> list(gen())
[1, 2]
```

In your case just use `next()`:

```
>>> def gen():
>>>     print("Hello")
>>>     yield 1
>>> x=gen()
>>> print(next(x))
hello
1
```